# Reset the cache in lru_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

Is there any way of over-riding the `lru_cache` in python?

Specifically if I have a function such as:

```
  import functools

  @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
  def function_of_interest(variables):

       ...
       return(processed_values)
```

Is is possible to reset the cache, and hence run-run the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is is possible to reset the cache, and hence re-run the function?

If my understanding is correct, you can just use `cache_clear` on the decorated function. If you've filled the cache by running it, this clears all indicators for you, that is:

```
function_of_interest.cache_clear()
```

Should result in a `cache_info` of:

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=None, currsize=0)
```

Comment: Do you know how to access it when the cache is on a property?

Comment: @Natim:  perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/55497384