# clear cache of @property methods python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some property methods in a Class and I want to clear the cache of this property at some point.

Example :

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def prop(self):
        # Compute some stuffs and return complex number
```

if I do self.prop.clear_cache(), here the error message I get :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.complex128' object has no attribute 'cache_clear'
```

clear_cache() works for functions but not for property methods. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to access the cache attributes on the getter attribute of the property object, so `.fget`. You can only access the property object *on the class*:

```
Test.prop.fget.cache_clear()
```

That's because the `@property` decorator replaced the `prop` function object with LRU cache, with a property instance.

Accessing the property name on an *instance* will always give you the result of the property getter, not the function object with cache controls.

Demo:

```
>>> import functools
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     @functools.lru_cache()
...     def bar(self):
...         print("Accessing the bar property")
...         return 42
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
Accessing the bar property
42
>>> f.bar  # cached
42
>>> Foo.bar.fget.cache_clear()
>>> f.bar
Accessing the bar property
42
```

Note that using a LRU cache this way means the cache storage is shared across all instances of the class, with separate results stored per instance (the cache is keyed on the `self` parameter). Clearing the cache will clear it for all instances. Given the default `maxsize=128` configuration, that means that only the property value for the most recently-used 128 instances will be cached. Access the property on instance #129 and then again an instance #1 will mean that the value is re-calculated for #1 as that instance's property value will have been evicted.